# Unimodularity: How are these notions related?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, terminology, hopf-algebras, locally-compact-groups

**1. Definitions**

- We call a Hopf algebra $H$ *unimodular* if the space of left integrals $I_l(H)$ is equal to the space of right integrals $I_r(H)$.
- We call a square integer matrix $M$ *unimodular* if $det(M)=\pm 1$.
- Apparently, there exists a notion of *unimodular group*: "a locally compact group whose left Haar measure equals its right Haar measure.”

**2. Questions**

- (How) are these three notions related?
- I haven't heard of unimodular groups, let alone locally compact groups or the Haar measure before. However, looking at this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3775470/752637), the unimodularity of a Hopf algebra seems to be somehow related to unimodular groups. How so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are related.

A Lie group $G$ is unimodular if and only if, for all $g\in G$, $\operatorname{Ad}g\colon\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}$ is a unimodular matrix when you choose a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$.

For a locally compact group $G$, we know there exists, up to multiplicative constants, a unique left-invariant Haar measure and similarly right-invariant.  We can also build a Hopf algebra of continuous functions $H\subseteq\mathbb{R}^G$.  Now you can choose to integrate a function with respect to the left-invariant Haar measure or right-invariant Haar measure and these give you the two integrals for the Hopf algebra.  If $G$ is unimodular, any left-invariant Haar measure is also right-invariant, so the two integrals agree, giving you the notion of unimodular Hopf algebra.